# Trouble with virtual attribute for payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, currency, virtual-attribute

Im currently trying to convert my price_in_cents field to the virtual attribute of price_in_dollars. I did some research and basically implemented everything from the railscast virtual attributes video, here is the link below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr7tD2GPiXU

At first, the column in my db was 'amount' for the money field. So I ran a

```
$ rails g migration add_price_in_cents_to_payments price_in_cents:integer
```

then,

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

My application is just a basic CRUD scaffold for creating new payments.

I added the getter setter methods into the `payment.rb` file, like so.

```
 class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :amount, :price_in_dollars, :from, :to
 # The price_in_dollars attribute is taking the place of :amount

 def price_in_dollars
   price_in_cents.to_d/100 if price_in_cents
 end

 def price_in_dollars=(dollars)
   self.price_in_cents = dollars.to_d*100 if dollars.present?
 end
end
```

And changed the form field to represent the new price_in_dollars attribute.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :price_in_dollars %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :price_in_dollars %>
</div>
```

But now when I submit a new payment, it returns the NoMethodError for my "new" and "create" methods in the payments controller. In the video, Bates does not even touch his controller. Here is my controller.

```
def new
    @payment = Payment.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @payment }
  end
end

# GET /payments/1/edit
def edit
    @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /payments
# POST /payments.json
def create
    @payment = Payment.new(params[:payment])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @payment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @payment, notice: 'Payment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @payment, status: :created, location: @payment }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Do I need to specify to pass in the `(params[:price_in_dollars])` in all my CRUD methods in the controller?
I'm a novice with only about 3 weeks of rails knowledge. Please help anyway possible.

Comment: @muistooshort nope, my fault. It still sends the same error though.

Comment: What are the exact error messages?

Comment: I was wrong that typo fixed it mostly, but I'll have to pass in a :precision option so that it doesn't just leave one digit of zero behind say a string of four numbers.